# GCM unreliable for chat app

Tags: android, socket.io, google-cloud-messaging

I depend on GCM to send/receive messages when the user is not connected via socket to a room. However, it may take several minutes for the messages to be received and it's not real time enough for a chat application. Are there any faster alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gcm is indeed not a good fit for chat applications. 
you have several options to consider, listed below. You should carefully read the SLA for each service , specifically regarding reliability , time frame for delivery etc.

1. using a xmpp based service (Google has one) instead of Gcm.
2. using an independent service like Pushy (https://pushy.me/).
3. using your own solution on the server side. you could use web sockets to notify clients about new messages from the server. this means you have to run your own server for communicating with the clients. If what you want is speed - you might benefit from this approach because when you have your own msg server you are not waiting in line with millions of other users to have your messages sent (like in Gcm and the others).

good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented Google's xmpp messaging and it's definitely faster although on a few rare occasions I have noticed some delay, about 3-4 mins. As far as free alternatives go this is probably the best option.